# Calculating the mean of different SMRs

Tags: anova, mean, standardized-mean-difference

I have the SMRs of different local areas. The same reference population was used for the standardization. The local areas were divided into 5 groups (group1, group2,...,group5).
I want to know if the groups have the same mean SMR or not.
I performed an ANOVA to test if the means of the SMRs between the groups are significantly different. The question is: is it correct/reasonable to calculate the mean of SMRs?

Comment: You should include the size of the groups, this is important when for ex. combining means. Better yet, do not average anything and use the whole data (with subtracted reference mean) and run an ANOVA.

Comment: How do I run an ANOVA if I have only one value per group?

Comment: That's what I said, do not aggregate anything to run an ANOVA.